# Combining unknown number of multiple lines between fix pattern in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad++ in windows.

I have a large text in the following format.

```
2C0_10B4 
TCD Signed Destination Address Offset
(DMA_TCD5_DOFF)
16
2C0_10B6
TCD Current Minor Loop Link, Major Loop Count (Channel
Linking Enabled) (DMA_TCD5_CITER_ELINKYES)
16
2C0_10B6 DMA_TCD5_CITER_ELINKNO 16
2C0_10B8
TCD Last Destination Address Adjustment/Scatter Gather
Address (DMA_TCD5_DLASTSGA)
32
2C0_10BC TCD Control and Status (DMA_TCD5_CSR) 16
2C0_10BE
TCD Beginning Minor Loop Link, Major Loop Count
(Channel Linking Enabled)
(DMA_TCD5_BITER_ELINKYES)
16
2C0_10BE
TCD Beginning Minor Loop Link, Major Loop Count
(Channel Linking Disabled) (DMA_TCD5_BITER_ELINKNO)
16
```

**I want to merge unknown number of lines between the lines which are starting from 2C0 into a single line. After this process all the text should look like this.**

```
2C0_10B4 TCD Signed Destination Address Offset (DMA_TCD5_DOFF) 16
2C0_109C TCD Control and Status (DMA_TCD4_CSR) 16
2C0_10C0 TCD Source Address (DMA_TCD6_SADDR) 32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!2C0)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak
`(?!2C0)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure we haven't `2C0` after the linebreak.

This will replace every linebreak that is not followed by `2C0`